# Changing callable for upload_to breaks migrations Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I had a callable for my image uploads which looked like this:

```
@deconstructible
class Rename(object):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        # some stuff and returns path
```

when I changed the `__init__` signature to :

```
def __init__(self, path, file_type):
        self.path = path
        self.file_type = file_type
```

I can no longer run makemigrations:

```
  File "/pathtomyapp/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 59, in Migration
    ('avatar', models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=myapp.models.Rename(b'profiles'))),
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Is there any way to solve this without modifying **Rename** functions signature in migration files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either change the migration file and provide the `file_type`

```
('avatar', models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to=myapp.models.Rename(b'profiles', 'file-type'))),
```

Or make the `file_type` argument optional in your `__init__` method.

```
@deconstructible
class Rename(object):
    def __init__(self, path, file_type=None):
```

Comment: simple and elegant `file_type=None` didn't hit me.